# Issues using apple revoke auth token rest api for unity mobile app

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, authorization

We have a mobile Unity app that uses Sign In With Apple. With new requirements to provide delete account to end users, apple demands that any authorization token used for sign-in be revoked. We have used the REST api provided by apple, and included the required parameters, and get a 200 OK response from the endpoint, but it seems to have no effect on the app. When we start the app our sign in manager checks the same apple sign-in token, and it is returned as authorized. The only success we've had to revoke the token is to use iOS settings Apps Using Sign In and remove our app.

Has anyone successfully revoked the Sign In With Apple token from a Unity mobile app, and if so, how did you do it?

Comment: It shouldn’t be done from within the app. The client secret requires a signature using a private key that shouldn’t be put out with the bundle especially with the team Id and key

Comment: Have you found what was causing the issue when you were getting 200 code but it didn't work?